# What kind of phrases request quantity?

Tags: phrases

For example:

> ***How far*** is it?
>
> ***How tall*** are you?
>
> ***How much*** does it cost?
>
> ***How long*** does it last?

I understand things like prepositional phrases where the phrase actually specifies a place or relationship to an object, as *"over the hill"* and *"on the lawn"* and *"under the blanket."* But I don't remember how quantity-related phrases are described. Would they simply be a subclass of interrogative phrases or sentences?

Comment: You can use "How many"

Comment: So let me see. "Far" is an adverb. "How far" would be a comparative adverb or adverb phrase?" "How many" would do the same thing. 

Still not sure if I am getting there.

Comment: _How_ is the _wh_-word that questions degree, manner, and means. It can occur before any adverb or adjective to ask about its degree (_how tall is she?_) or before any clause to ask about its manner (_How did she look on stage?_) or means (_How did she open it?_). It's pretty much strictly a question word -- _how_ can't be used as a regular relative pronoun (*_That's the way how she opened it_).